# Command Prompt Simulate Click in Another Window

Tags: window, command-prompt

I have no idea where to start about creating the solution for this, as I am only experienced in JS/HTML/Java/Lua/C++. What I'm trying to do is, from the command prompt, click at any place in an already opened window. For example, the already opened window could be a program called "Gorg" with the title/name "Gorgiant", and it would just need to simulate a click anywhere in that window if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try AutoHotKey  .  It has commands to check if a window exists .